# Find a Dictionary Values in Paragraph and Return NA if paragraph doesn't have Dictionary values

Tags: python, list, performance, dictionary

**Suppose i have this random words of Paragraphs as a list:**

```
t = ['protein and carbohydrates Its is a little heavier pulsus widely used and is a versatile ingredient',
 'Tea contains the goodness of  Natural Ingredients Cardamom Ginger Tea bags Disclaimers As per Ayurvedic texts',
 'almonds are all natural supreme sized nuts they are highly nutritious and extremely healthy',
 'Camel milk can be consumed by lactose intolerant people and those allergic to cows milk',
 'Healthy Crunch  Almond with honey is an extra crunchy breakfast cereal for a delightful start to your mornings']
```

**Dictionary as**

```
d = {'First': ['Tea','Coffee'],
     'Second':  ['Noodles','Pasta'],
     'Third': ['sandwich','honey'],
     'Fourth': ['Almond','apricot','blueberry']
    }
```

**The Code i Have written is very slow and also i want to display 'NA' for the Paragraphs that does'nt matched to any text**

**CODE**

```
get_labels = []
get_text = []

for txt in t:
    for dictrow in d.values():
        for i in dictrow:
            for j in txt.split():
                if i == j:
                    print(j)
                    print(txt)
                    get_labels.append(j)
                    get_text.append(txt)


pd.DataFrame(list(zip(get_text,get_labels)),columns=["whole_text","matched_text"])
```

**Finally after creating the Dataframe Output is:**

```
     whole_text                                       matched_text
0   Tea contains the goodness of Natural Ingredie...    Tea
1   Tea contains the goodness of Natural Ingredie...    Tea
2   Healthy Crunch Almond with honey is an extra ...    honey
3   Healthy Crunch Almond with honey is an extra ...    Almond
```

**But the Output i want is:**

```
     whole_text                                       matched_text
0   protein and carbohydrates Its is a little ....      NA 
1   Tea contains the goodness of Natural Ingredie...    Tea
2   Tea contains the goodness of Natural Ingredie...    Tea
3   almonds are all natural supreme sized nuts th...    NA
4   Camel milk can be consumed by lactose intoler...    NA
2   Healthy Crunch Almond with honey is an extra ...    honey
3   Healthy Crunch Almond with honey is an extra ...    Almond
```

I have 2 Issues:
a) I want to add 'NA' for the paragraph that doesn't matched to any text dictionary values like above table.
b) How do i optimize this code to run it faster because i am using it on large dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `set` intersection *power*:

```
paragraphs = ['protein and carbohydrates Its is a little heavier pulsus widely used and is a versatile ingredient',
 'Tea contains the goodness of  Natural Ingredients Cardamom Ginger Tea bags Disclaimers As per Ayurvedic texts',
 'almonds are all natural supreme sized nuts they are highly nutritious and extremely healthy',
 'Camel milk can be consumed by lactose intolerant people and those allergic to cows milk',
 'Healthy Crunch  Almond with honey is an extra crunchy breakfast cereal for a delightful start to your mornings']

d = {'First': ['Tea', 'Coffee'],
     'Second':  ['Noodles', 'Pasta'],
     'Third': ['sandwich', 'honey'],
     'Fourth': ['Almond', 'apricot','blueberry']
}

words = set(w for lst in d.values() for w in lst)
match_stats = {'whole_text': [], 'matched_text': []}
for p in paragraphs:
    common_words = set(p.split()) & words
    if not common_words:
        match_stats['whole_text'].append(p)
        match_stats['matched_text'].append('NA')
    else:
        for w in common_words:
            match_stats['whole_text'].append(p)
            match_stats['matched_text'].append(w)

df = pd.DataFrame(match_stats)
print(df)
```

The output:

```
                                          whole_text matched_text
0  protein and carbohydrates Its is a little heav...           NA
1  Tea contains the goodness of  Natural Ingredie...          Tea
2  almonds are all natural supreme sized nuts the...           NA
3  Camel milk can be consumed by lactose intolera...           NA
4  Healthy Crunch  Almond with honey is an extra ...        honey
5  Healthy Crunch  Almond with honey is an extra ...       Almond
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `in`

```py
values = set(v for l in d.values() for v in l)
txt_and_label = []  # string of tuples

for line in t:
    # checks if v in line and assigning in the form of (line ,label_value)
    match = [(line, v) for v in values if v in line]
    if not match:
        match = [(line, 'NA')]
    txt_and_label.extend(match)

pd.DataFrame(txt_and_label, columns=["whole_text", "matched_text"])
```